# Recuperar datos del LocalStorage y mostrarlos en el DOM

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con mi trabajo de conversor de monedas y es que cuando mando a recuperar los datos del localStorage para que se muestren en el DOM al recargar la página no quedan ahi y se desaparecen, la función es la siguiente:

```
//Datos de inputs
const primerDivisa = document.getElementById('primer-divisa')
const segundaDivisa = document.getElementById('segunda-divisa')
const ul = document.querySelector('.lista-resultados')

function calcular() {
  const primerMonedaIngresada = primerDivisa.value 
  const segundaMonedaIngresada = segundaDivisa.value

// Los datos que se almacenan son de una API que me da valores de distintas divisas

  fetch(`https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/58f679169d6ab2828a7dcda0/latest/${primerMonedaIngresada}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    const taza = data.conversion_rates[segundaMonedaIngresada]
    infoDeCambio.innerHTML = `<b>1 ${primerMonedaIngresada}</b> es igual a: <b>${taza.toFixed(2)} ${segundaMonedaIngresada}</b>`
    segundoValor.value = (primerValor.value * taza).toFixed(2)

        botonConvertir.addEventListener('click', botonClick)
      })
    }
```

Esta es la funcion que muestra el código en el DOM y a la vez los almacena en localStorage. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal? :(

```
//MOSTRAR CONTENIDO EN EL DOM
function botonClick() { 
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.classList = 'lista'
  const agregarEnLista = ul

  li.innerHTML = `La conversión de <b>$${primerValor.value} ${primerDivisa.value}</b> es igual a: <b>$${segundoValor.value} ${segundaDivisa.value}</b>`

  agregarEnLista.appendChild(li)
  li.appendChild(borrarResultados())
  almacenarEnLocal.push(li.innerHTML)

  almacenarEnStorage()
}

  //AGREGAR CONTENIDO AL LOCALSTORAGE
function almacenarEnStorage() {
  let resultados = JSON.stringify(almacenarEnLocal)
  localStorage.setItem("Conversiones", resultados) // <= ARREGLO ALMACENADO EN EL LOCALSTORAGE

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { //RECUPERAR DATOS DEL LOCALSTORAGE
    obtenerLista.forEach( function(elementoLista) {
      botonClick(elementoLista)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar imágenes de los datos obtenidos que se están guardando en el localStorage? Y así verificamos que están pasando los datos a esa función almacenarEnStorage(). También por lo menos puedo notar que si, le puedes retornar los datos al front, pero requieres tenerlos en formato de JSON y así podrás pintarlos en el front.

Comment: Por si te interesa este es el repositorio del proyecto :) 

https://github.com/MartinVijarra/conversor-de-divisas

Comment: tu código de DOM jamás lee de localStorage, en todo el código que muestras  solo veo que escribes no que lees

Comment: ¿Cómo se inicializa/asigna obtenerLista? A parte de en la función almacenarEnStorage, ¿en dónde más se realiza esa iteración de obtenerLista?

Answer (score 0):

- En primera instancia para agregar en el localStorage, si, con el método que estás colocando 'setItem'
- Ahora para obtener esos datos es con el método 'getItem'

Ejemplo de guardado en el LocalStorage:

```
const meses = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo'];
localStorage.setItem('meses', JSON.stringify(meses))
```

Ejemplo de obtención de esos datos guardados en el LocalStorage y en formato JSON:

```
const mesesArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meses'))
```

Así puedes obtenerlos en el front, y pintarlos donde quieras.